# Why has ping started to resolve hostnames to IPv6 addresses?

Tags: ping, ipv6

Why would my computer (Vista Business) begin to start pinging using IPv6?  I have not to my knowledge made any change to enable this.

When I ping a local computer with it's hostname, ping has started to display the IP6 address it resolves to and not the IPv4 address.

Any ideas?

Comment: Because computer can understand only numbers and not name like ( 0 and 1).And also when you work on domain there is a Reverse Look-up zone which has done this function.

Comment: you can force IPv4 by using `ping -4 hostname`

Answer (score 4):

It's probably because when ping looks up the hostname your DNS returns an ip6 address. Check with whomever is in charge of your DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

Just go to network card properties, uncheck the IPV6 address option and restart the machine. default ping to hostname will resolve to ipv4 address.

Comment: Not an answer to the question which is just "why". Also you will want IPv6 support when possible.